# What are the differences between embedded processor and non-embedded processor?

Tags: virtual-memory

I read a statement which says

> Almost all non-embedded processors, and many embedded processors, support virtual memory

Anyone who can explain the difference between both types

Answer (score 0):

An **embedded processor** is a type of microprocessor designed into a system to control electrical and mechanical functions. Embedded processors are usually simple in design, limited in computational power and I/O capabilities, and have minimal power requirements. At a basic level, embedded processors are a CPU chip placed in a system that it helps control. You may have heard about RISC architecture. RISC and non-RISC type architectures are common amongst embedded processors.

**Non-embedded processors** on the other hand, provide multitude of services for multi use purposes, and attempt to abstract the operation of the hardware from a casual user. Virtual address space is increased using active memory in RAM and inactive memory in hard disk drives (HDDs) to form contiguous addresses that hold both the application and its data. For sure, all multi purpose processors are supporting virtual memories.